# Duplicate pages with ?s parameter

Tags: urls, seo, duplicates, parameter

I scanned my website with a duplicate content scanner tool, and it gives me lots of duplicate content pages with `?s` parameter at the end, which are crawled by Google.

How can I remove these pages?

Examples:

```
http://solei.md/croaziere/?s
http://solei.md/bilete-de-avion/?s
```

And so...

I looks that it has something to do with search.

What should I do with these pages?

Answer (score 0):

adding the parameter as exception directly inside webmaster tools is an option for you. However you have canonical on the right place, so it's not something you should be bothered